# Передача javascript используя php

Tags: php, javascript

Например есть файл ex.js который содержит обычный alert("AAA");
Данный скрипт вызывается с удаленной машины:

```
<script src="http://192.168.0.1/ex.js">
</script>
```

Все работает.
Хочу чтобы данный скрипт передавался php скриптом.
То есть вместо ex.js сделал exp.php и вставил следующий код:

```
<?php echo 'alert("AAA");';?>
```

Однако таким образом не работает. Точнее в браузере работает, но в необходимом мне клиенте - нет. Сравнив в WireShark первый и второй случай выявил разницу в Content-Type. В рабочем варианте -- application/x-javascript, во втором случае text/html.

Хочу сделать это для того, чтобы впоследствии использовать некоторое условие, в зависимости от которого будет высылаться нужный JS скрипт.

Comment: То есть вопрос в том, как в php установить Content-Type?

Comment: Да, разобрался.
В php нужно указать в начале:

Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");

Comment: @Skywave
Хотел узнать, а можно ли передавать таким же образом img?
Ну допустим у меня есть конструкция:
'<script></script>'
'<img src>'
'<script></script>'
Могу ли я ее всю отправить также через echo?

Comment: Любой запрос можно проксировать через пхп и файлы тоже. Любые. ( ну или почти любые))

Comment: @Skywave
Каким образом можно, используя один php файл передать 2 разных JS скрипта.
т.е. у мне нужно передать 2 конструкции `<script></script>` и `<script></script>` раздельно.

Comment: Два файла за раз не знаю как. Но js файлы отлично склеиваются в один. По пути можно еще и минифицировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В exp.php нужно указать в начале:

```
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
```